# How to minimize white space with thymeleaf 3?

Tags: thymeleaf

When process html with template engin, we may get a large file which contains useless white spaces everywhere. To minimized the spaces the engin processed is an important thing to do to accelerate the transform speed.
There are two kinds of spaces which can be minimized . One is between the tags. Anther one is between the attribute gaps. The first one seems to be easy to remove(AbstraceTextProcessor). The latter one seems hard to process. I wrote a processor but seem too inefficient.

[SpacesDialect](https://github.com/zjnu-acm/judge/blob/ae77b64e02a4a3bd4f7278cfcc3839ae54bc4d19/src/main/java/cn/edu/zjnu/acm/judge/config/thymeleaf/SpacesDialect.java)

[AttributesInnerWhitespacesProcessor](https://github.com/zjnu-acm/judge/blob/ae77b64e02a4a3bd4f7278cfcc3839ae54bc4d19/src/main/java/cn/edu/zjnu/acm/judge/config/thymeleaf/AttributesInnerWhitespacesProcessor.java)、[EmptyTextProcessor](https://github.com/zjnu-acm/judge/blob/ae77b64e02a4a3bd4f7278cfcc3839ae54bc4d19/src/main/java/cn/edu/zjnu/acm/judge/config/thymeleaf/EmptyTextProcessor.java)

Any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf doesn't want to add it in their core.. instead it was added in ecosystem.. check out https://github.com/connect-group/thymeleaf-extras

Comment: It seems to be excellent If I'm working with thymeleaf 2.x. Thanks for the link. But I guess I don't need it now.